How to make the name of the first author consistent with the rest in the bibliography?
I am using biblatex with biber backend:
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        natbib=true,
        style=authoryear,
        maxcitenames=1,
        mincitenames=1,
        maxbibnames=99,
        uniquelist=false,
        uniquename=false,
        hyperref=true]{biblatex}

Here is how the bibliography looks like:

==================================
Notice that for the first author, we have: {last name}, {first name}
For the following authors, however, we have: {first name} {last name}.
Is there a way to make it consistent?
i.e., the name of the first author is also displayed as {first name} {last name}.

are you sure you want this? the format you show is pretty standard for author-year systems. if you put the first name of the first author first, it is much harder for a reader to find the entry corresponding to a given label, which begins with the last name of that author. and it would then be very unclear how to sort the entries. would you still sort on last name? then it looks strange. would you instead sort on first name? but that makes it even harder for readers to find entries. similarly, it would be confusing to make the list 'consistent' by flipping subsequent names - too many commas.

By default biblatex formats the first name in a list of names differently (in family-given order) than the other names in the list (in given-family order) in some styles (namely in those styles where the sorting is determined by the [family] name of authors and there are no other labels to go by). That makes it easier for your readers to locate the relevant reference, because the word that determines sorting the most is the first word in the entry.
You can add
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}

to your code to get "Given Family" format for all names in the list. But this will make it harder to navigate the bibliography at the end, because the sort order is no longer determined by the first word of the entry.
Or you use
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

and list all names in inverted "Family, Given" order. This will lead to a lot of commas.
The default setting that you are seeing is
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}


Thank you! This is exactly the solution and explanation I needed.
